# ch.qos.logback.contrib json logging alternative

Tags: spring, logback, spring-logback, logback-classic

I have the below appender from my logback.xml file and I want to replace the ch.qos.logback.contrib library usages with something else because that library is vulnerable and not maintained anymore.
Do you guys have any ideas of some libs that I can replace this with?

```
<appender name="RollingFileJSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/json/app.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.json.classic.JsonLayout"> <!-- this -->
            <timestampFormat>yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX</timestampFormat>
            <timestampFormatTimezoneId>Etc/UTC</timestampFormatTimezoneId>
            <jsonFormatter class="ch.qos.logback.contrib.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatter"> <!-- and this -->
                <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
            </jsonFormatter>
        </layout>
    </encoder>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily and when the file reaches 10 MegaBytes -->
        <fileNamePattern>logs/json/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>
</appender>
```

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is an appender which will log into a json format, on the same line.

I tried using the spring logging and also to simply use a pattern layout but it does not work properly (exception would not get added inside the json object, but outside and on a new line).

```
<layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
    <pattern>{"timestamp":"%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX}", "level":"%level", "logger":"%logger", "message":"%msg", "thread":"%thread"}%n</pattern>
</layout>
```

Comment: You may use [logstash-logback-encoder](https://github.com/logfellow/logstash-logback-encoder)

Comment: If possible, I would like to stick with logback :(